# Is there any reason for performing full URL encoding on a POST body

Tags: c#, windows, http

I'm currently working on a C# WinForms application which makes calls to a couple of remote web services. In investigating a bug relating to strings containing ampersands, I came across the following method which 'encodes' POST bodies for the *other* web service (which doesn't have the ampersand issue, admittedly.)

```
object o = row.Values[i]; //some object
Type valueType = o.GetType();
if (valueType.Name.Equals("String", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
{
    o = o.ToString().Replace("&", "%26");
}
```

I did a bit of WTF at this, but then thought, is there an actual reason for performing full URL encoding on POST bodies? Surely the only two risk points are ampersands and question-marks?

Comment: Anything with HTTP that contains URLs, generally needs to be URL encoded. Also, use UTF-8 character encoding.

Comment: ...and percent characters... I would just stick to the spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit one-sided.  There's only reason to encode POST data is if the other side is expecting it to be encoded.  e.g. if the content type of the post data is "x-www-form-urlencoded" then, yes, you need to url encode the data.  If the other side *doesn't* expect it to be urlencoded then don't...

Typically, you don't need to urlencode data going to a web service because you've got flexible end-points.  If you've got a web service that is expecting to be called directly from a web page (e.g. through a form post) then urlencoding may be done by the browser directly--in which case the web service needs to accept url-encoded (and thus anything *else* that wants to communicate with it).